# Caixa no meio da página de acordo com a resolução

Tags: css, posicionamento

Estou tentando posicionar uma caixa no meio da tela e que independente da resolução o texto que tem dentro dela não saia da caixa...
Pois bem, eu consigo duas coisas: posicionar ela no meio, contudo quando eu redimensiono a minha janela, o texto sai da caixa; e fazer a caixa aumentar junto com a resolução, porém a caixa fica encostada no topo da página.

Aqui eu coloquei o html e o css: http://jsfiddle.net/SemNomeTol/s7ztmbL4/4/
Pra vocês verem já com a imagem...

Comment: Oi, Zebra, é importante colocar o código aqui, o Fiddle tá sem funcionar direito o dia inteiro...

Comment: @brasofilo, nossa achei que era minha rede que tava com problema. Penei para salvar meu exemplo lá. Hehe.

Comment: Vou colocar aqui, desculpem, a hora que fui hospedar tava sem problemas, agora realmente notei o erro no site.

Comment: @Zebra, confira no Meta: [Posso mostrar só um link pro meu site com problemas?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1913/201) e também [Perguntas só com Fiddle](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1912/201)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não sei se compreendi bem sua questão, mas pelo que entendi você deseja manter seu `form` sempre ao centro da tela não importando a resolução da tela, e que ela caiba seu conteúdo (meu exemplo é para um conteúdo de tamanho mensurável, não sei se lhe atende).

O que minha solução tem a mais do que seu exemplo é o seguinte (acompanhe os comentários do código):

```css
left: 50%; /* metade da pagina */
top: 50%; /* metade da pagina */  
width: 400px; /* utilize um tamanho que seja suficiente para seu conteúdo horizontal */
height: 260px; /* utilize um tamanho que seja suficiente para seu conteúdo vertical */
margin-left: -200px; /* utilize a metade do valor setado no width para trazer o elemento ao centro horizontal da tela */
margin-top: -130px; /* utilize a metade do valor setado no height para trazer o elemento ao centro vertical da tela */
```

Além das alterações que apontei anteriormente o elemento deve continuar com a `position: relative;` ou `absolute` se for o caso.

Segue [exemplo online](http://jsfiddle.net/fernandoleal/s7ztmbL4/10/) para lhe ajudar a compreender a solução proposta.

Para telas menores, como tablets e smartphones você pode criar [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries), adicionando uma regra similar a essa em seu `css`:

```css
@media (max-width: 410px) {
  form {
    width: 260px;
    height: 340px;
    margin-left: -130px;
    margin-top: -170px;
  }
}
```

Acompanhe [exemplo online](http://jsfiddle.net/fernandoleal/s7ztmbL4/14/) atualizado (diminua a tela para um `width` menor que `410px`, para testar).

[Exemplo no Plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/G7J3DkiZZ14Co5yIRnww/preview), para o caso do jsFiddle estar com problemas com citado por @brasofilo.

Comment: Cara, obrigado pela resposta, eu tava querendo usar com %,  não px. Mas se eu não conseguir, vou ter que por assim mesmo, fico pensando se numa tela pequena o cara não terá que desaproximar e em uma tela maior o cara não terá que aproximar porque ficaria muito pequeno. Entendeste? Mas sua solução dá certo sim.. valeu

Comment: @ZebraDoMal, acompanhe a edição a resposta, e veja se atende suas necessidades, e se você deseja criar layout's responsivos, em todo seu aplicativo, considere a opção de utilizar um  `framework ` que lhe fornece  `layouts ` em grid, que lhe facilitará a vida. Indico o [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/) que utilizo desde a versão 2.*.